# is there any way to run a GIS (Esri, Qgis or mapinfo) on a Windows8 RT tablet?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapinfo

I am looking for a good idea to run a GIS program on a Dell XPS 10 with the Wind.8 RT.Thanks for any

Comment: Are you sure it's RT?

Comment: the ArcGIS app is not a GIS! Unless of course you shell out $$s for an ArcGIS Online account. Dont let anyone from ESRI tell u otherwise

Comment: This is more of a Rant rather than an Answer. I fail to see what it contributes to the Q&A

Answer (score 6):

**GRASS** will run on an Raspberry Pi (ARM) so should have no issues on Windows RT.

[image]

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

Comment: did you compile it on the PI or cross compile?

Comment: on the pi via windows8>puTTY>ssh (as use it as a headless server too)

Answer (score 5):

For QGIS no it will not run on RT because it's ARM and we don't build for that yet.  I have no doubt that it can be done, just not done yet.

Comment: Though GRASS will run on a raspberry pi (ARM) http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=19160

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS app is available for Windows 8.

> The Windows 8 app provides a preview of features that integrate the
>   new touch-centric view of Windows 8 and Windows RT with the ArcGIS
>   Online mapping platform.

More info [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/smartphones/windows8-app).